# how to give title and datetime property dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/3537/)**

```html
UTC<br/>
<time id="divUTC" title="" datetime=""></time><br/>
Your Local Time with respect to above UTC time<br/>
<time id="divLocal" title="" datetime="">
</time>
```

how can i print the result of **#divutc and #divlocal** inside **title** and **datetime** of **time tag** through the jquery??

Comment: document.getElementById("divLocal").title = ''some title'

$('#divLocal').prop('title', 'your new title');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get time like this.

```
    var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    onlyTime = moment(localTime).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

and set the attributes like this

```
 $('time').attr('title',onlyTime);
 $('time').attr('datetime',localTime);
```

Comment: seems not working, if that be explained in fiddle would be really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from javascript like this

document.getElementById("divLocal").title = ''some title' ;

Or in JQuery like this

```
$('#divLocal').prop('title', 'your new title');
```

Comment: i need the result to be printed in title and datetime, the above code seems a static one from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery attr method:

```
$("#divUTC").attr("title", "UTC time title");
$("#divUTC").attr("datetime", "2008-02-14 20:00");
```